# Requesting more information about overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an HTML/CSS application, and I'm a bit stuck.
Let's say that I have 2 elements positioned next to eachother `display: inline-block`

Every element has again a couple of elements which are placed next to eachother.
See the following illustration that tries to explain it:

[image]

So, the image below describes 3 different levels of elements:

- Level 1: Red - Outer element
- Level 2: Yellow - Wrapper element
- Level 3: Green - Content

In HTML, this could be constructed writting like the following:

```
<ul id="holder">
    <li>
        <div>
            <div class="col">Col 1</div>
            <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="col">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The UL represents the red element, the LI represents the yellow elements and the DIV elements represents the green elements.

Now, let's say that our red element has a fixed width and I place the overflow on hidden. This means that when I resize the page, the elements on the right dissapear when they don't fit the page.

But here the problem arizes, when I do resize the window, and the window becomes too small to render everything, immediately, the latest LI element is not visible on the screen anymore.

Is there any CSS way to make sure that no the LI element are hidden but the DIV elements inside the LI? When both DIV elements are hidden, off course the LI element can be hidden aswell since it's empty?

If there's no CSS way to do this, anyone minds putting me in the right direction by using JavaScript or something else?

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLqfe4z8/3/) to explain it a bit more.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` disappears from view because it's in `display: inline-block`.
As soon as the window isn't wide enough, it moves **below** the first li.
You can see this happen if you release the `#holder`'s height (`height:auto`).
The solution is to add `white-space : nowrap` to force the `li` to stay in one line.

Updated fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/zLqfe4z8/4/

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem of your elements hiding because there's not enough width, it's because they're wrapping because there's not enough width (and then being hidden by the `overflow: hidden`).

[You can see this happening](https://jsfiddle.net/zLqfe4z8/5/) if you remove the `height` constraint on your wrapper:

```
#holder { overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid red;  }
```

The fix is simple, [stop it from wrapping](https://jsfiddle.net/zLqfe4z8/6/) using `white-space: nowrap`:

```
#holder { white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid red; height: 52px; }
```

Comment: Argh, we posted the same answer at the same time =)